# alternative to button ng-click in angularjs

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, internet-explorer-11

I am working on angularjs application. I have a button in my home page, when user click on the button, it has to hit the controller and from backend get the data and show on the browser. Everything is working fine in chrome and firefox but not working in IE. Tried hard to find a alternate solution to resolve but with no luck, any suggestions would be helpful.

html :
 
            
               Login

```
spring controller:

@RequestMapping(value = "/getData", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody
    List<String> getMyData(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("In MyDataController"); //printed only when navigated through chrome
    //logic here
    //return statement
}
```

PS: When the same above code is executed in IE11, it is not hitting the spring controller but works fine is chrome and safari. What could be the alternate way to achieve the same functionality as the button does in angularjs and which works both in IE and chrome.

--EDITED--
js controller:

```
 myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope, MyService) {
    $scope.btnAdminDetails= function () {
    alert("In btnAdminDetails, js controller"); //this is called both in IE11 and chrome
    console.log("In controller");
    MyService.retrieveData().then(
    function (response) {
        alert("response back from spring controller");
        if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
        $scope.IEBrowser = true;
        $scope.myData = response;
        } else {
        $scope.IEBrowser = false;
         $scope.myData = response;
        }
    },
    function (errResponse) {
        $rootScope.showError("Internal error" + errResponse);
    });
    }
    $scope.btnAdminDetails();
    });
    //service code
    _myService.retrieveData= function(){
    alert("service call");//called when tested from both IE and chrome, but issue is from IE the java controller is not getting called from here..
    console.log("In Angular Service above $q.defer ");               
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    console.log("In Angular Service below $q.defer");
    var randomh=Math.random();
    var repUrl = myAppURL+'/myControllerr/getData.form?x='+randomh+"";
    $http.get(repUrl).then(
    function (response) {
        deferred.resolve(response.data);
    },
    function(errResponse){
        deferred.reject(errResponse);
    }
    );
    return deferred.promise;
    }
I have added Math.random to the request URL in the service call.
```

In IE11, **when i click on the button only the alert `btnAdminDetail, js controller` in controller is shown, the other alert statements or the console.log statements are not printed**.

Comment: can you tell me that is on click of button, btnAdminDetails function is running? or not?

Comment: yes it is running and calling the angular controller also, issue is it is not hitting the spring controller.

Comment: Kindly show us your MyService code as well.

Comment: Please check using IE Developer Tools whether there is any error logged to the console.

Comment: @WasifKhan -Please see my post above, i have added few more details and the service call. No errors are shown in IE console. But one thing i noticed is when developer tools is opened in IE, the behavior is correct, and it is hitting the spring controller too.

Comment: @AniketV - No errors are shown in the console, but when developer tools is opened , it is behaving correctly and the spring controller is invoked. Any suggestions how to resolve this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be MyService._myService.retrieveData().then() ?

Comment: @user7833845 check out console on server side when sending request from IE, is there any exception?

Comment: no, it is working perfectly in chrome and many other controllers are working fine with the syntax as mentioned in above code. Issue is not that, My issue here is if i have a button and when i click on that it is not hitting the spring controller when IE11 is used, and no errors are shown. But when i open developer tools in IE and then test it, it is hitting the spring controller ad code is working fine.@Vivz

Comment: @WasifKhan - I have checked server console is also blank as the browser console.But as i said one strange thing is in IE when i did f12(developer tools) and tested, it is hitting the spring controller.

Comment: I think I get your question little bit, instead of debugging, use `console.log("In controller")` use it instead of alert and `console.log("In Angular Service")` use it below `var deferred = $q.defer();` and tell me what is on your console. Do not open insert debug point.

Comment: @WasifKhan - executing that give me a minute,thanks

Comment: @WasifKhan - In controller        
 In Angular Service above $q.defer       
In Angular Service below $q.defer                , those are the statements printed both in IE and chrome when page is loaded as well as when i clicked the button. But somehow in IE , spring controller is not getting called.

Comment: in network tab on IE, call is going right and what is the response of the call? when not debugging

Comment: @WasifKhan - network tab in IE is always blank, it is not showing any URL. Please see my edited section in my post above.

Comment: @user7833845 Chat me on my skype ID: muhammad.vaaceph

Answer (score 0):

Add value inside button tag

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="login" ng-
     click="btnAdminDetails()">
       Login
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I already tried adding that, but no luck. I'm editing my post with my latest tried version now. Please have a look

Comment: Whats's the IE version that you are using

Comment: IE11 is the version and  no errors are shown in the console. @Vikash Kumar

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking your application is not working in IE11 .So do the following the changes.

1.Add the following line in head tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />
```

2.Use strict mode for your controllers

```
    (function () {
    "use strict";

    function yourController($scope, $rootScope ) {
        // Do things
    }

}());
```

3.Change the web.config file with respect to IE11

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=11" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score -1):

there is no such alternative of ngClick but you can also use ngDblClick in place of ngClick for more details please refer this link:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

Comment: My issue is not an alternative but should work in IE and obviously i cannot use ngDblClick as i cannot say to user to double click to get a functionality instead of a single click on button. Any suggestions for my above post related would be helpful.@Mayank Sharma